# DatabaseMetaData.getColumns() giving error with SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

We have a database code in place for a long time which is running successfully with Progress DB. Recently, we tried it with SQL Server 2008 with JDBC 4 driver .It gave below exception:

**Database '%' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.**

```
DatabaseMetaData conMD = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet columns = conMD.getColumns("%", "%", m_Table, "%");
```

Could anybody please help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

If you get the list of catalogs before?

With the method **getCatalogs()**

```
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getCatalogs()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says: you cannot pass a wildcard for the database (catalog) parameter. Wildcards are only allowed for the schema, table and column names.

Use null instead.

```
conMD.getColumns(null, "%", m_Table, "%");
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this code and it works too. My confusion is why my code is working with progress DB if % is not valid value of catalog.Second,I'm not able to understand usage of % by reading javadoc of DatabaseMetaData. Its bit confusing :( .It will be much useful if you provide an example with a string.

Comment: The Javadoc is actually pretty clear: all other parameters are documented as "the xxxx *pattern*", whereas the first one is documente as the "catalog *name*".

Answer (score 0):

```
conMD.getColumns(connnection.getCatalog(), "%", m_Table, "%");
```

instead of giving % ,`connnection.getCatalog()`will fix the issue.Interesting thing is that the code works with Oracle,MySql and Progress . Only Sql Server is throwing the error.

Comment: Oracle does not have a "catalog" concept. As far as I know the driver simply ignores that parameter.